# Microsoft Graph : filter request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to make a request on Microsoft Graph but I can't find the answer. (https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/graph-explorer)

I would like to get all the messages that they are NOT in a category :

This request, give all the messages with the category 'oa' :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c eq 'oa')

I would like to have the opposite :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=not categories/any(c:c eq 'oa')
but this request failed...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use 'ne' for "not equal" instead of 'eq':

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c ne 'oa')
```

Comment: I have already try this but it doesn't work : any(c:c ne 'oa') means that if he finds another category the condition is true, it will work I think with all(c:c ne 'oa') but the operato all doesn't exist..

Comment: @Stef: Can you clarify what you mean? My request should give you all messages where the category is not 'oa'. I thought that's you wanted?

Comment: @Stef: Please clarify or accept my reply as answer. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, if I do your request I have mails with 'oa' category, example :
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('c32f90eb-9bb3-423c-90b2-b690cf6c1327')/messages",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories%2fany(c%3ac+ne+%27oa%27)&$skip=18",
    "value": [
        {
...
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-08-26T08:37:11Z",
            "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAABGNHZMMHVeT5cuoqXePCJ1AAAFjAMw",
            "categories": [
                "oa"
            ],
...
}

Comment: I think you are right, you would need the 'all' operator to be supported here. Which it is not ("BadRequest", "Filter not supported."). Although it is part of the OData protocol.